# Java gui with login authetnication via mysql database not working and changing logic

Tags: java, mysql

I've got a GUI that has a MySQL jdbc which checks to make sure the user has inputted the correct login information, but for some reason, even if the information is listed in my database it's saying it's not. I am hoping that someone can help me with the logic of my code as well. Thanks

Comment: Is the password stored in plain text? If you get any results, then you shouldn't need to check the return result, infact you could simply do select count(*) from person where...

Comment: Yes it's in plain text, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
 if (rs!=null && rs.next()) {
                orgUname = rs.getString("username");
                orPass = rs.getString("password");
            } //
```

to

```
while(rs.next())
{
orgUname = rs.getString("username");
                    orPass = rs.getString("password");
}
```

As `per your logic select * from table_name where username=? and password=?` what if the password is wrong.If password is wrong then resultset is empty and its no use while loop.
So I would suggest you to take username from your gui like this way.

```
select * from Table_name where username=?
```

Then inside while loop get the original password from the database like this way.

```
orPass =rs.getString("password");
```

then now match the orginal password with entered password like this way

```
password.equals(orPass)
```

Comment: @jameskerr not working means what?are you getting any error or what?

Comment: It's compiling, but its still not granting me access into the gui. 100% im using correct information.

Comment: @jameskerr change your logic little bit.Take username from GUI.And from the DataBAse collect the password like SELECT * FROM person WHERE username=?.Then match the password from the database with that of entered passsword from the GUI.IF equals then do something else do something.Hope you understood.

Comment: @jameskerr OK I will help but you need to modify your question.Just post the DataBase part and in your question write need suugestion or some thing.Its because my answer(to change your logic) will not be in relevant with respect to this question

Comment: @jameskerr Sorry i would have said JDBC part instead of database part

Comment: @jameskerr check my answer.If you still have any queries then you can ask

Comment: So from your above answer, Should I just remove `AND password=?` from my select statement and `orgUname = rs.getString("username");` from the if statement and `&& username.equals(orgUname))`

Comment: @jameskerr yes,my logic will also work fine if suppose wrong username is entered

Comment: @jameskerr then do one thing just print the username and password and check manually what are they

Comment: Hey I updated my code to print out the tables and their values. It's printing them out correctly, but when i use the correct information it's still not letting me login

Comment: @jameskerr I think you are confused.I do not understand why you are retrieving all the username and password from database.According to you recent code this will only work with the username and password that is present at the last row.Try just enter the last row of the table person(username and password) in your GUI and try login.It will work

Comment: @jameskerr good to be helped,well delete all unnecessary comments because these comments will not be helpful for future users

Comment: How can i make it so it uses any row in the table, It also seems to only check for passwords and not usernames.. So i can have a blank username but use the last row's password.

Comment: @jameskerr I really want to help you and clear all your queries but here writing comments like this way is not the proper way. In Stackoverflow question are meant for future users who have same error like you so they can directly use my answer.Hence these comments will not be useful to them.You can post another question and ask what all your queries there

Comment: Ok thats understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next())
{
uname = rs.getString("username");
pass = rs.getString("password");
}
```

Comment: Why? Assuming that the OP is expecting only a single result (fora given user) rs.next() in the of statement seems reasonable...